# Configuring Griddler with SendGrid and Gmail for Work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, sendgrid, mx-record, griddler

I am in need of help figuring out a how to set up incbound email with Griddler and Gmail for Work. I've got a Rails 4 that I'm trying to configure to receive incoming emails using Griddler and SendGrid. I followed the instructions on the [Griddler readme](https://github.com/thoughtbot/griddler) exactly. Next I created a tunnel to my localhost environment using ngrok.io. I then went into the SendGrid web app and created a webhook to catch emails going to `example.com` and send them to the url `abc123.ngrok.io`.

So far, I think I've got the setup correct. Next I set up an MX record in my domains DNS zone file. The host is `@` and it points to `mx.sendgrid.net`.

Here is where things get tricky for me. My site has Gmail for Work set up. I'm not super particular on the details, but essentially, I want a way for users to send a message to `foo@bar.example.com` and have it routed to Griddler, rather than Gmail. The format of the email address is not terribly important except that it must be dynamic in the sense that `foo` can be replaced with anything and it will still be routed to Griddler, as long as the domain is `bar.example.com`. If the domain is just `example.com`, then it should be routed to Gmail.

I've not had much luck finding resources on how to set this up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure 2 separate MX records, one for example.com, and one for bar.example.com. Have the subdomain record point to SendGrid, and have the domain use gmail's MX.